# primary key and foreign key

Tags: sql-server-2008, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have 3 tables

```
   Student    Loan    Book
 - StudentID  LoanID  BookID
```

which foreign keys do i need to set so when given the student name, search all loan from that student and display the book detail

Comment: I'm assuming Students <-> Loans is 1:1 but Students <-> Books is many:many?

Comment: It depends. You need to decide how the relationships work and that will dictate the table design. Can a loan have only one book or more than one book? Same question for the relationship between students and loans. These are things you should include in your post to help people understand the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a start with such vague requirements:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Students
(
  StudentID INT PRIMARY KEY
  -- , other columns about students
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Loans
(
  LoanID    INT PRIMARY KEY,
  StudentID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Students(StudentID)
  -- , other columns about loans
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Books
(
  BookID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  -- , other columns about books
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.StudentBooks
(
  StudentID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Students(StudentID),
  BookID    INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Books(BookID)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Student
--------      
Studentid -PK

Loan
---------
Loanid  - PK
Studentid -FK


Book
-------
Bookid  -PK
Loanid   -FK
```

Comment: Why would a book be related to a loan?

Comment: A student takes out a loan. A loan could contain one to many books. This is a valid model in my opinion.

Comment: Interesting... I would assume that a student gets a loan, and buys books, I don't know if I've ever heard of a case where the loan officer wants to know what books you bought.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what columns you have, assuming you have studentId in student table, it would be best candidate for primary in Student and foriegn in other two tables.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use studentid as foreign key in both the other tables...because you want to search on the basis of student. so this key should go in the remaining tables