# Loan System on VBNET

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

From my [Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9237876/1180498)

What I want to do is to add a new student loan and the program checks the book title if loan exists, does
not allow the same loan to be created. There is no limit on the number of loan
placed by the student.

How do I write the code as above in VB.NET

Note: 1 book Per Loan number

Add Loan Form
[image: Add Loan form]

Comment: Wouldn't you want to check that a loan for the `book title` exists for a student, rather than the `LoanID`?

Comment: yea that would make much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `LoanID` is also an auto-incrementing number? If not, it should be and then also make it a primary key.

Also, the `Book` record will want an auto-incrementing primary key field and then you can link the two record by id, and check the book_id (or similar) in the loan table for a particular student.